# Nginx 1.25.2 HTTP/3 works over CURL, but doesn't work in any browser

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, networking, quic, http3

I am trying to configure **nginx 1.25.2** with **HTTP/3** support on **Ubuntu 22.04**. I build it using **BoringSSL** library. But when I try to connect to my server using browser, I don't get anything.("Unable to connect" in Firefox and "This site can't be reached" in Chrome for example).

Here is **nginx -V** output:

```
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1 (compatible; BoringSSL) (running with BoringSSL) 
TLS SNI support enabled configure arguments: 
--prefix=/etc/nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-debug 
--with-http_v3_module --with-cc-opt=-I../boringssl/include 
--with-ld-opt='-L../boringssl/build/ssl -L../boringssl/build/crypto'
```

Here is my server part in **nginx.conf**:

```
 server {
        #listen 443 ssl 
        #http2 on;
        listen 443 quic reuseport;
        server_name  example_myserver;
        ssl_certificate cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key key.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
        location / {
            add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
```

Using above config I can get HTTP/3 response using **http3 curl**:

```
HTTP/3 200 
server: nginx/1.25.2
date: Wed, 23 Aug 2023 08:12:55 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 615
last-modified: Tue, 22 Aug 2023 14:25:41 GMT
etag: "64e4c565-267"
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
accept-ranges: bytes
```

and using https://github.com/cloudflare/quiche http3client tool I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I reach the same server via browser, nothing there("Unable to connect" in Firefox and "This site can't be reached" in Chrome). UFW is turned **off** completely. By the way, **http1** and **http2** works without any problem. Maybe someone had similar problem and could help me or maybe I missed something? I will be grateful for any useful info.

Comment: I would start by looking at the nginx log.  Then see what the browser sends (Firefox has a Network tab in developer tools; or you could look at a network trace).

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like we come up with the same situation.

Conclusion: If you use a browser, your server will be ask to have a valid certificate. Offically

my nginx version

```
❯ /opt/nginx-1.25.2/sbin/nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.25.2
built by gcc 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1 (compatible; BoringSSL) (running with BoringSSL)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: 
--prefix=/opt/nginx-1.25.2 
--with-debug 
--with-http_v3_module 
--with-http_v2_module 
--with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module 
--with-http_gunzip_module 
--with-http_slice_module 
--with-stream 
--with-stream_ssl_module 
--with-stream_ssl_preread_module 
--with-stream_realip_module 
--with-compat 
--with-threads 
--with-file-aio 
--with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-cc-opt=-I../boringssl/include 
--with-ld-opt='-L../boringssl/build/ssl -L../boringssl/build/crypto'
```

server part in nginx.conf

```
    server {
        #listen       80;
        #listen       8443 ssl;
        listen       443 ssl;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl;
        listen       443 quic;
        listen       [::]:443 quic;

        server_name  example_myserver;

        ssl_certificate     server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key server.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1.3;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        root   /home/www/;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        location / {

            add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';
            add_header x-quic 'h3';
        }
```

when i try bilibili/quiche, i add the param --disable_certificate_verification=true, which means just skipping the check for SSL, and it works all the time.

```
./simple_quic_client \
  --disable_certificate_verification=true \
  --host=127.0.0.1 --port=443 \
  "https://www.example.org/index.html"
```

Soooo.. i guess MAYBE, it's the SSL's problem? Remember the Chain of CA in System.

reference: hope will help you figure out the problem.

[1]https://github.com/bilibili/quiche/

[2]https://bagder.github.io/HTTP3-test/

for [2], it turns out that not every website works in browers either. Surprisingly.. but still a little confuse?

:) have a nice day anyway.

BTW, unfortunately, i fail to compile the curl with http3 support. If you can show how it works, tell me THE DAMN RIGHT method, i will appreciate for that.

my curl version

```
./curl --version                                               ✘  23:25:51 
curl 8.4.1-DEV (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/8.4.1-DEV OpenSSL/3.0.10 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 ngtcp2/0.19.1 nghttp3/0.15.0
Release-Date: [unreleased]
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli HSTS HTTP3 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSocket
```

it looks like i make it, but

```
./curl --http3-only https://quic.rocks:4433/                     ✔  23:25:55 
curl: (3) HTTP/3 is not supported over a HTTP proxy
```

thank God!